# How can I get element from TitleView in other pages?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I have a progress bar in the title view which I set in AppShell. I want to increase the progress bar when I move forward in pages. How can I get the progress bar in other pages in order to increase the value?

```xml
<Shell.TitleView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="0,10,0,0">
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <ImageButton Source="back_button_icon.png" x:Name="BackButton" Clicked="BackButton_Clicked"/>
                <Image
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Margin="170,0,0,0"
                Source="top_bar_icon.png"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            

            <ProgressBar
                x:Name="ProgressBarPages"
                Progress="0.2"
                ProgressColor="#9179FF"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set this in `AppShell` then given you have named your progress bar with an `x:Name`, you can get hold of a reference to your `ProgressBarPages` control within the `AppShell` code behind file. And you can access the shell from anywhere with `Shell.Current`. So my suggestion is to add a method to your shell e.g.

```cs
public void IncreaseProgress(float val)
{
    // TODO: Some kind of range checking here...
    ProgressBarPages.Progress += val;
}
```

Then call it from wherever you want with:

`(Shell.Current as AppShell)?.IncreaseProgress(.1f);`

However, I thought that `TitleViews` were set on the `ContentPage`. If they are then you may be best off using Data Binding to set your progress value in a view model that is available wherever you need to change the setting or perhaps use MessagingCenter to use an observer pattern to update the value?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do something similar to this I like to involve something like `IMessenger` from [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger). I prefer this method because this way you can communicate all kinds of messages between unrelated classes. There are many other libraries that implement this pattern `EventAggregator` from [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) works the same.

In order to update you progress you need to define a message like so:

```
public class ProgressValueChangedMessage: ValueChangedMessage<double>
{
     public ProgressValueChangedMessage(double increment) : base(increment)
    {        
    }
}
```

Then in shell you listen for the message:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ProgressValueChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
   // increment progress
});
```

And finally you have to send a message in you other pages when the progress should increase.

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ProgressValueChangedMessage(value));
```